# How to Update/Install python

Tags: python

I want to install pip on my windows but I get an error saying

```
     ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip 
     (from versions: none)
     ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip
```

Comment: how u get the error

Comment: I used a python file called get-pip.py, and then I run it with the code python get-pip.py

Comment: python and windows version

Comment: what do u mean? python runs perfectly

Comment: did you use python 3

Comment: nope Python 2.7

Comment: go with python 3 since Python 2.7 end of support is near

Comment: so i delete python 27 and get python 3?

Comment: yep ; https://pythonclock.org/

Answer (score 0):

First check pip version by using the following command then upgrade
pip --version

pip install --upgrade pip

this will upgrade pip version

Comment: i get a message saying 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Download get-pip.py
Go to action prompt 
python get-pip.py
it should install pip.. Please try download and install

Comment: I did that and don't worry guys I fixed the problem today